# Exit early from Kernel#select on socket close

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpsocket

I have a very simple socket app:

```
# Server
server = TCPServer.new(2000)
loop do
  client = server.accept
  sleep 10
end

# Client
s = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 2000)
th1 = Thread.new do
  begin
    Kernel.select([s], nil, [s], nil)
    puts 'Select returned'
  rescue => e
    puts "Select raised #{e}"
  end
end
th2 = Thread.new do
  sleep 0.5
  s.close
end
[th1, th2].map(&:join)
```

Now, what I want to happen is, if while the client is hanging waiting for the server to respond, the client's socket is closed by a different thread, the `Kernel#select` call should exit immediately and raise an error. This is what happens on MacOs, however on Linux, the call to `select` hangs indefinitely (or until the timeout is hit).

1. Is there any way to get around this?
2. I think the system call I need is poll(2), but that doesn't seem to be available in ruby?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get around this?

Instead of trying to interrupt the waiting thread by closing the local socket, include the read end of a pipe among the IO objects it is `select`ing on.  Then another thread can interrupt the `select`ion by writing to or closing the write end of the pipe.  That has the added advantage that it allows the client to distinguish between a local termination request and a remote disconnection.

Something along these lines, for example:

```rb
rd, wr = IO.pipe

# ...

#
# thread 1
#

sock = # ...

# ...
ready = Kernel.select([sock, rd], nil, [sock, rd], timeout)
if ready.nil?
  # handle timeout ...
elsif ready.flatten.include? rd
  # handle local termination request ...
else
  # handle socket ...
end

#
# thread 2
#

# Interrupt thread 1
wr.close
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves my problem? If I select on the read end of the pipe, will terminating the write end of the pipe cause the select to fail immediately? Also, any chance you could provide a code example?

Comment: @NeilShweky, Closing (or writing to) the write end of the pipe will make the `select` *succeed* immediately, because the read end can then be read without blocking.

Comment: @NeilShweky, added example code

Comment: this is extremely helpful thank you! Note that when you close the pipe in the second thread, an IOError is raised from Kernel#select, it doesn't return... If you write to the pipe it returns as you described.

Comment: The IOError is only raised if the socket is closed...

Comment: @NeilShweky, I wouldn't necessarily have predicted the IOError in the event that the local socket was also closed, but of course you should be able to work with that.  However, I do observe that my recommendation was to use the pipe "***Instead of*** trying to interrupt the waiting thread by closing the local socket".  Closing the local socket when something else is using it is Not Nice(tm).